# Looking for equivalent in postgresql for merge update implemented in mssql

Tags: postgresql, merge, database-migration

Have to migrate the below MSSQL code to  postgresql
Looking forward for postgresql code which does the following.
**MSSQL codee**

```
MERGE TO_SubFamy AS TARGET   
    USING 
    (
                SELECT SF.Id as SubFamyId, 
                CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Id)>0  THEN 'Young' ELSE 'OLD' END as ActiveYn
                FROM 
                TO_SubFamy SF
                RIGHT JOIN TO_SubFamyAutomationLink SFA ON SF.Id=SFA.SubFamyId
                RIGHT JOIN TO_AUTOMATiON A ON A.Id = SFA.AutomationId and A.State='Active'
                WHERE SF.Status <> 'not exits'
                GROUP BY SF.Id 
                EXCEPT
                SELECT Id, status from TO_SubFamy WHERE Status <> 'not exits'
        ) as SOURCE  
          ON TARGET.Id = SOURCE.SubFamyId   
          WHEN MATCHED THEN  
                UPDATE SET TARGET.status = SOURCE.ActiveYn;
```

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with MySql is rather limited, but the statement looks suspiciously like the same statement in Oracle. (Not a surprise as it wasn't supported until after Oracle bought MySql.) And a little research seems to confirm.  
The merge statement is typically used to either insert or update based on the result of the ON statement. But another semi-common use is strictly to update as the syntax is somewhat easier in many cases as you do need to essentially repeat the select statement. Since your statement uses only the WHEN MATCHED clause it is the latter use being employed. So the translation is just a UPDATE. I think the follow satisfies your need.

```
 with source (subfamyid,activeyn) as 
      (select sf.id, 
              case when count(a.id)>0  then 'Young' else 'OLD' end  
         from to_subfamy sf
        right join to_subfamyautomationlink sfa on sf.id=sfa.subfamyid
        right join to_automation a on a.id = sfa.automationid and a.state='Active'
        where sf.status <> 'not exits'
        group by sf.id 
       except
       select id, status from to_subfamy where status <> 'not exits'
      )        
update to_subfamy as target        
    set status = source.activeyn     
  where target.id = source.subfamyid;
```

**Disclaimer:** As you neglected sample data and expected results the *query has not been tested*. However, right joins look suspicious, appears that all rows from table "to_automation" will be kept even if they do not exist in either of the others.